# Refresh an API token for custom extension/plugin in Joomla/Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, access-token, joomla-extensions

I need to build a site using Joomla or Wordpress where I can display a stat from another API. The API needs an api_token and it needs to be refreshed regularly as it expires after 30 days.

I can build a simple website with any of these CMS. But the issue I am facing is with the API. If I build a simple module/plugin with the API parameter, then what is the way to refresh the token regularly? I do not have access to the cron on the website hosting.

Is there any way to run a scheduler from the site and update the settings in Joomla/Wordpress CMS? Or what other approaches can be followed?

Comment: Have a look at the [WP Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) pages, it's probably what you are looking for.

Comment: @flomei this, this might be helpful. do you have any idea about similar feature in Joomla?

Comment: No, sadly not. But as cronjobs are a unix system feature, you can always call a script or whatever right through the system cron and schedule your task that way.

Comment: thanks. I know i can set cron separately, but i do not have access to that. that is why i was searching something within the cms.

Comment: There are services which can run a cronjob for you. So, if you need to call a publicly available script, that might be a solution if nothing else works.